# ClassCastException: LongWritable cannot be cast to BytesWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, classcastexception

I'm just reading data from HDFS through Spark. It throws `ClassCastException` at line no 6. I never used `LongWritable` in my code, no idea how the data was in that format.I declared tuple2 Object as Tuple2, so tuple2._2() should be BytesWritable but its returning LongWritable in Runtime, thus throwing ClassCastException when i try to access getBytes(). This code didn't throw any complie time errors. My question is how tuple2._2() returns LongWritable when i declared it as ByteWritable.

Note : I'm not using MapReduce Concepts and also I'm not creating Jobs explicitly. So I can't use `job.setMapOutputKeyClass` and `job.setMapOutputValueClass`.

```
        JavaPairRDD<IntWritable, BytesWritable> hdfsContent = sparkContext.sequenceFile(hdfsPath, IntWritable.class, BytesWritable.class);
        JavaRDD<FileData> lines = hdfsContent.map(new Function<Tuple2<IntWritable, BytesWritable>, FileData>()
        {
            public FileData call(Tuple2<IntWritable, BytesWritable> tuple2) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException
            {
                byte[] bytes = tuple2._2().getBytes();
                return FileData.parseFrom(bytes);
            }
        });
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Can you post line number 6?

Comment: I'm getting error at the line byte[] bytes = tuple2._2().getBytes();

Comment: I declared tuple2 Object as Tuple2<IntWritable, BytesWritable>, so tuple2._2() should be BytesWritable but its returning LongWritable in Runtime, thus throwing ClassCastException when i try to access getBytes(). This code didn't throw any complie time errors. My question is how tuple2._2() returns LongWritable when i declared it as ByteWritable.

Comment: I can see declaration for tuple2. But what is tuple2._2()? is it typo error?

Comment: @Ravindra : It not an Typo. tuple2 is object of Scala Tuples(class that can contain a miscellaneous collection of elements). In short, tuples are like key,value pair. tuple2._1(), tuple2._2() will return key and value respectively.

Comment: Ok. Can you post the code where you are populating this Tuple ( tuple2)? When you are putting key value pair, is the value attribute proper?

Comment: @Ravindra : Its already there. The data is fetched in the format of JavaPairRDD<IntWritable, BytesWritable> in hdfsContent Object from the HDFS file (line no 1)

Comment: Can you check last code snippet at this link? http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-SequenceFile-Java-API-Repeat-Key-Values-td353.html

Comment: @Ravindra : Already done. Not very helpful.